# Android Tabs Layout

Tags: android

I have an Tab Activity with 4 tabs.
Each of tab is showing me the list view.
Suppose i m on 4th tab and dragged the list view to the last position and after that i click on 3rd tab and again when i go to 4th tab it is not refreshing and showing me the last visible screen. Actually i want to show the list view again from 1st element.

is tabs refresh automatically or we need to do it programmatic??

pls help me..

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```